# EF Core 2.0 Migrations Not Recognized by Package Manager Console

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, .net-core-2.0

I'm trying to add a migration for a .net core 2.0 web app through the package manager console in visual studio 2017.  I receive the error: "The EntityFramework package is not installed on project ". However, EntityFrameworkCore 2.0 is installed.

I've tried:

- the enable-migrations command (although I don't believe this is necessary anymore)
- the add-migration command
- "Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 2.0.0" through the PMC
- re-installing entityframeworkcore 2.0 through the NuGet package manager

Is there some other configuration that needs to be done somewhere else?

Since EF Core migrations work on my .Net Core 1.1 project could this issue be related to .Net Core 2.0?

Cheers!

Comment: Odd - I assume you've installed the 2.0 SDK? https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

Comment: Yes, I updated Visual Studio then downloaded the 2.0 SDK and started a new project.

Comment: please provide your project's `*.csproj` file

Comment: Do you have only 1 project in solution or your EF is installed in separate data project?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the EF6 commands are running. You can unload them with the following command.

```bsh
Remove-Module EntityFramework
```

The EF Core PMC commands should be available to use after installing the following package.

```bsh
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Answer (score 0):

> The EF tools for the command-line interface (CLI) are provided in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet.

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations

Comment: `Tools.DotNet` package is for dotnet cli. e.g dotnet ef commands. It does not contains PMC commands like `Add-Migration`

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours for this issue and finally update Visual Studio 2017 15.4.0 Preview 2.

Hope this help.